# Core Plot Bar Chart animation

Tags: iphone, animation, core-animation, core-plot

Hi how i can implement the grow up bar chart with animation?
I only start work with Core Plot so i need little help.

Comment: Particular problem description and maybe your code snippet should be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Core Plot plot is a Core Animation `CALayer`. You can animate the plot using the standard techniques, for example, to fade it in or stretch the size from zero to full height.